# What properties determine ClientDataSet field sizes?

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I have an app that uses ClientDataSets and local file storage. Some of the info is displayed in a DB grid, and I found it was getting cut off--the first 500 characters or so of a string were displayed, but the underlying fields needed to be longer. So I went back to my code and increased the size of the underlying FieldDefs and also their display widths. I also created a new dataset (at design time). Finally, I ran the application, and created a new database. Nevertheless, only ~500 chars were displayed.

Where should I look to see what's limiting my field lengths?

Comment: The field size (the maximum number of characters in the string field type) is stored in the [`TField.Size`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField.Size), so as the first I would suggest you to check this value.

Comment: How do you expect to display 500 or more characters in a DBGrid? (Can you say *major* scrolling issues? I see repetitive stress injuries in your user's future. <G>) The typical way to do this is to display partial text, and allow the user to double-click to read the rest; when they do, you open a secondary window with a TMemo or TRichEdit or other control that displays the entire text in a readable format.

Comment: @Ken, +1 to your comment (I'd like to see this mentioned in the answer ;-). I hate grid columns trying to autosize a size exceeding more than one page scroll from a current position. It's impossible to read the content without dragging the scrollbar manually, thus I would prefer a hint window or show the rest of the content by a double click.

Comment: @Ken, It seems odd at first blush, but the grid has only two columns and the text is 9 or 10 pt. The long TStringField entries are rarely edited. The UI's visual appearance is similar to a table in a word processor. I posted a partial screenshot at http://www.csulb.edu/~acolburn/screenshot.doc

Comment: @AlC, a TDBGrid is a poor choice for your UI (as is your choice of a Word document to post a sample screenshot <g>). You might look at `TVirtualStringTree`, which has the functionality you seem to need, or a replacement for `TDBGrid` like [ExpressQuantumGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid). `TDBGrid` support for this isn't there out of the box.

Comment: @Ken, It's actually TMS's DBGrid replacement; I was trying to keep my question simpler by leaving out superfluous info. Clearly I failed :-)

Comment: :-D Apparently. Your question has nothing to do with ClientDataSets (as an ftString width of 2500 works fine here, and ftMemo is virtually unlimited) or TDBGrid (as you're not using it). It might help to start over with a new question, mentioning that you're using the TMS replacement and including a png image of what you're trying to achieve. :)

Comment: @Ken OK, I'll vote to close the question ... Thanks for your help (as always).

Comment: @AlC, I didn't say to close this one. :) It might be useful to someone in the future. My suggestion was that you start a new one with the actual question you want to ask, providing the details you've given in the comments here, so you can get help with solving the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suspect you're running into an internal limitation of `TDBGrid` column widths, since a column that displays 500 characters would be more than a typical screen wide. (You can check this if you want to wade through the VCL source; start with `Grids.pas`.)

Typically, a `TDBGrid` doesn't display a lot of text in a single column. It leads to a lot of scrolling by the user, and horizontal scrolling to read wide text is extremely annoying to most people.

The usual way of doing this is to use an `ftMemo` type field, which can contain virtually unlimited text content. When the column is assigned to a `TDBGrid`, the grid column displays `(MEMO)`, and the application handles a click or double-click on the column to display a secondary form with a `TEdit` or `TRichEdit` to display/edit the full contents of the column.

Here's an example of a `TDBGrid` attached to a `TClientDataSet` named `CDS` with the following columns defined (useless, but an example) using `CDS.FieldDefs` in the Object Inspector:

```
Column      Persistent Name    FieldType    Size
------      ---------------    ---------    ----
ID          CDSID              ftInteger     0
Name        CDSName            ftString     25
Notes       CDSNotes           ftMemo        0
```

Since the underlying dataset doesn't exist, I assign a `FileName`, and use the following code to create it at runtime:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not FileExists(CDS.FileName) then
  begin
    CDS.CreateDataSet;
    CDS.Active := True;
    CDS.InsertRecord([1, 'John Smith', 'This is some longer text'#13'for testing.']);
    CDS.InsertRecord([2, 'Fred Jones', 'A note about Fred goes'#13'here for now.']);
    CDS.Active := False;
  end;
  CDS.Active := True;
end;
```

I put a `TDataSource` on the form, and set it's `DataSource` to `CDS`. I added a `TDBGrid`, and set it's `DataSet` to `DataSource1`.

In the Object Inspector, choose the `TDBGrid`, go to the Events tab, and add the following to the `OnCellClick` event (just for display, of course):

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
begin
  if Column.FieldName := 'CDSNotes' then
    ShowMessage(Column.Field.AsString); // Display other form here instead
end;
```

Here's the display after clicking the `CDSNotes` column on row 1 of the `TDBGrid`:

[image]

If you *must* display partial content of a longer text column in the `TDBGrid`, you can use something like the following:

```
procedure TForm2.CDSNotesGetText(Sender: TField; var Text: string;
  DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  // Again, a trivial example using an arbitrary chunk of the first 20
  // characters just for demo purposes.
  if DisplayText then
    Text := Copy(Sender.AsString, 1, 20)
  else
    // Not for display only; return all the text.
    Text := Sender.AsString;
end;
```

Doing so with the sample app above changes the display to this:

[image]